# Set Camera Parameters Exception

Tags: android

I have a "strange" problem! Am using 3-4 devices for testing but I have a problem with Samsung Tab|Pro (SM-T230). When am trying to get a picture with the back camera it crashes on setPictureSize method (no issue with front camera).

What I really want to do is to maintain the same aspect ratio on the preview and captured image. So every time that I am switching am doing this configuration.

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
Camera.Size size = getBestPreviewSize(screenWidth, screenHeight);
parameters.setJpegQuality(80);
parameters.setPreviewSize(size.width, size.height);
parameters.setPictureSize(size.width, size.height);
mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
```

**EDIT**

**getBestPreviewSize() Method**

```
private Camera.Size getBestPreviewSize(int width, int height) {
    Camera.Size result=null;
    Camera.Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();
    for (Camera.Size size : p.getSupportedPictureSizes()) {
        Log.i("PictureSize", "Supported Size: " +size.width + " height : " + size.height);
    }
    for (Camera.Size size : p.getSupportedPreviewSizes()) {
        Log.i("Preview Size", "Supported Size: " +size.width + " height : " + size.height);
        if (size.width<=width && size.height<=height) {
            if (result==null) {
                result=size;
            } else {
                int resultArea=result.width*result.height;
                int newArea=size.width*size.height;

                if (newArea>resultArea) {
                    result=size;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked that the camera supports the size you're setting? Are you using `getSupportedPictureSizes()`?

Comment: Crashes how? Exception? Segmentation fault? Post the trace from logcat, please.

Comment: @MikeM. Yeah on both cameras and both previewSize & pictureSize.There is an intersection size.

Comment: @Jitsu Exception: Parameters set failed!